# How to find a solution with three unknowns in Python

Tags: python

How can I solve this in Python?

[image]

Something feels like it would be a loop or some kind of solver.
I know I can solve it by trial and error, but that's not the point.

Comment: Are you just looking for a solution or all possible solutions?

Comment: Surely there are infinite solutions? Since you can have any level of precision with each x value, there is no *one* solution to this?

Comment: I looking for solution in the set of all possble solution

Comment: Do you want only integer or any real solutions? The set of integer solutions is finite, not the other one.

Comment: There's no real trial and error involved for real solutions; by simple algebra, `x1` has a trivial upper bound of 1200 (non-inclusive); `x2` has an upper bound of `1200 - x1` for any given `x1`, and then `x3 == 1200 - x1 - 3*x2`. The problem is only interesting from a programming perspective if the solution must be 3 *integers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @dantechguy, there are infinite answers, but that doesn't mean we can't get python to tell us that for sure.  Best route for systems of equations solving is `sympy`. Check it out here: [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html)

The following will solve your system of equations and tell you for each variable, and tell you the bounds of each.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import S

x1,x2,x3 = S('x1 x2 x3'.split())
Eq = [1*x1 + 3*x2 + 5*x3-1200, x1>0, x2>0,x3>0]
sol = solve(Eq, x1),solve(Eq, x2),solve(Eq, x3)
display(sol)
```

This outputs:

```
((0 < x1) & (0 < x2) & (0 < x3) & (x1 < oo) & (x2 < oo) & (x3 < oo) & Eq(x1, -3*x2 - 5*x3 + 1200),
 (0 < x1) & (0 < x2) & (0 < x3) & (x1 < oo) & (x2 < oo) & (x3 < oo) & Eq(x2, -x1/3 - 5*x3/3 + 400),
 (0 < x1) & (0 < x2) & (0 < x3) & (x1 < oo) & (x2 < oo) & (x3 < oo) & Eq(x3, -x1/5 - 3*x2/5 + 240))
```

If you're working in a jupyter, use the following to make things show up nicely typeset with LATEX:

```
display(solve(Eq, x1))
display(solve(Eq, x2))
display(solve(Eq, x3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are infinite solutions, so as long as you have two of the x values you can find the third required to reach 1200.

So say you have `X1` and `X2`, some simple algebra tells us:

`5*X3 = 1200 - X1 - 3*X2`

and then

`X3 = (1200 - X1 - 3*X2) / 5`

so there you have found `X3` with values for `X1` and `X2`. To find a variety of solutions, you could fill `X1` and `X2` with random numbers and then get the third `X3` to match.

Comment: But OP says _I know I can solve it by trial and error but..._

Comment: @Parth Shah I think by "trial and error" they mean trying random combinations of all three variables until they match 1200